# Secure boot is on, now grub isn't starting properly and there's no BIOS button for my Samsung 270E

Tags: grub2, bios

So, I was trying to boot into recovery mode through Ubuntu so I can update grub because after I had installed Ubuntu I haven't been able to boot windows. Everything was fine up until I updated grub and it asked for a Secure Boot password, and I made one. I would disable secure boot but I have to use windows to go the BIOS since there's literally no button for my Samsung 270E laptop to take me to BIOS mode.
I do realize I'm a noob lmao

Answer (score 1):

When the Samsung logo screen appears, press the `F2`-key repeatedly.

Comment: I've tried all keys.. Unfortunately none of them have worked, I just can't access the BIOS or the boot menu

Comment: You may have fast-boot enabled in UEFI-BIOS and when you boot it is maybe so fast, that you don't have a chance to hit a key to enter BIOS anymore. Boot to Ubuntu, open terminal, command                                  `sudo efibootmgr  --timeout 5`
Reboot and try again if you can go to BIOS now with `F2`-key. If possible, disable fast-boot in BIOS, reset timeout later in Ubuntu-terminal with `sudo efibootmgr --timeout 0`.